# Box shadow not working in safari on input form

Tags: css, safari

I have applied everything.

```css
.gf_bottom_address input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<input name="input_1" id="input_4_1" type="text" value="" class="large pac-target-input" placeholder="Enter your home address" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: can you show your html as well please

Comment: <input name="input_1" id="input_4_1" type="text" value="" class="large pac-target-input" placeholder="Enter your home address" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 2):

I've added `!important` to the piece of code that should be making the change (`-webkit-appearance: none;` to `-webkit-appearance: none !important;`

```css
.gf_bottom_address input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<input name="input_1" id="input_4_1" type="text" value="" class="large pac-target-input" placeholder="Enter your home address" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off">
```